# Ramda Js: Setting property on an object using a value from the same object

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Using Ramda Js, I need to create a function that can set one object property using the value of a different property on the same object. My attempt so far is as follows:

```
var foo = R.set(R.lensProp('bar'), 'foo' + R.prop('foo'));
var result = foo({foo:"bar"});
```

Desired result:

```
{foo:"bar", bar:"foobar"}
```

Actual result:

```
{foo:"bar", bar: "foofunction f1(a) {... etc"}
```

Clearly I'm misunderstanding something here, and any insights into how to approach this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lenses are not a good fit when the value of one property depends on the value of another property. A lambda is probably best here:

```
const foo = o => R.assoc('bar', 'foo' + o.foo, o);

foo({foo: 'bar'});
// => {foo: 'bar', bar: 'foobar'}
```

Answer (score 11):

I had just coded something like the answer from @davidchambers and then made a points-free version, only to show how much simpler the lambda actually is.  Rather than throw it out, here's how bad it looks in comparison:

```
var foo = (obj) => R.assoc('bar', 'foo' + obj.foo, obj);
var foo = R.converge(R.assoc('bar'), [R.pipe(R.prop('foo'), R.concat('foo')), R.identity]);
```

These two, with an intermediate version are available on the **[Ramda REPL](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.19.1)**

Comment: Cheers Scott! Interesting how long winded the points-free version needs to be.

Comment: I'm not guaranteeing that there isn't a more concise points-free version.   But the lambda expression is already fairly clean.

Answer (score 0):

I would slice the issue into 2 parts: first you need to copy the `foo` property of an object to `bar`, then change `bar`'s value. There is no out of the box solution in ramda for the 1st, but you can use `evolve` for the second:

```
import { curry, assoc, compose, evolve } from 'ramda'

// String -> String -> {k: v}
const copyPropAs = curry((from, to, obj) => assoc(to, obj[from], obj))

// String -> String -> String
const prefix = curry((value, string) => value + string)

const fn = compose(
  evolve({
    foo: prefix('foo')
  }),
  copyPropAs('foo', 'bar')
)

fn({foo: 'bar'})
```

I know, that it's not all point free, but with this way the problematic part is isolated to a point where it can no longer be broken to smaller parts, and we can always come back to those to find better implementations.